# Characterizing non-zero polynomials on semialgebraic sets: a kind of positivstellensatz generalization

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials, real-algebraic-geometry

A polynomial positivstellensatz is an algebraic characterization of polynomials which are positive on a semialgebraic sets. Is there a similar kind of characterization which can determine whether a polynomial is never zero?

One "straightforward" answer to this is to simply apply a positivstellensatz to the square of the polynomial, but I am wondering if there is an approach which avoids the squaring operation.

To motivate this further, let $S = \{ x \in {\mathbb R}^n : f_i(x) \geq 0\}$ be a basic closed semialgebraic set. There are various kinds of positivstellensatz methods, here I will use Putinar's (along with its implied assumptions on $S$, which are mildly stronger than compactness): if a polynomial $p$ is positive on $S$, then $p$ can be written in the form $$p = \sigma_0 + \sum_i \sigma_i f_i$$ where $\sigma_0, \sigma_i$ are polynomial sums of squares (sos). Such a characterization lends itself to semidefinite programming, which is part of the underlying motivation behind this question.

If $S$ has only one connected component, determining whether $p$ is never zero on $S$ is trivial: simply apply the positivstellensatz to $p$ or $-p$, one of which will succeed if $|p| > 0$ on $S$. My question is more interesting in the case when $S$ has multiple connected components. As mentioned, one possible approach is to apply a positivstellensatz to $p^2$, which in the case of Putinar's asks whether there exists sos $\sigma_i$ such that $$p^2 = \sigma_0 + \sum_i \sigma_i f_i.$$
However, note the equality constraint is now quadratic in the coefficients of $p$. In my application, I am attempting to find a polynomial $p$ such that $|p| > 0$ on $S$ (along with other conditions), and so this quadratic constraint becomes more of an issue, i.e., if the coefficients of $p$ are the unknowns, then the quadratic constraint is not convex, one cannot easily apply semidefinite programming, and the optimization/feasibility problem in finding $p$ is much harder, potentially NP-hard. One way out of this is to search among all polynomials of the form $q = \sigma_0 + \sum_i \sigma_i f_i$, and try to find a $q$ whose symmetric positive semidefinite Gram matrix is of rank one, a convex proxy of which is to minimize the trace of $q$'s Gram matrix. This can work sometimes, but not always.

In short, I am wondering: are there any kind of characterizations of non-zero polynomials on compact semialgebraic sets without resorting to squaring the polynomial and applying a positivstellensatz? I am relatively new to these methods in real algebraic geometry, so I may have missed something in my literature search; any insights from the community here would be much appreciated.

Comment: what you call "semialgebraic set" is actually called "basic semialgebraic set". Do you mean the latter? Or you really mean "semialgebraic set", as a finite union of basic ones?

Comment: Yes - I've always thought of this problem in the context of basic semialgebraic sets, and am happy to discuss the question in this context if it helps.

Comment: You are also not precise in the question setting. What do you mean by $p$ is non-0 on $S$? Do you mean  $p(s)\neq 0$ for all $s\in S$? Or that $S$ is not *identically* 0 on $S$, i.e there exists $s\in S$ with $p(s)\neq 0$ ?

Comment: Non-zero here means $p(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in S$. I have edited the question to clarify this, thanks for pointing out the slight ambiguity.

Comment: I don't  know how Putinar's Positivstellensatz helps you to find a certificate of strict positivity. The elements of the quadratic module $Q(S)$ on $S$ are nonnegative on $S$, in general, and SDP would allow you to find a certificate of nonnegativity. For positivity one would need something like Krivine–Stengle Positivstellensatz, IMHO. Then for positivity of $p$ one looks for $q_1, q_2\in Q(S)$ s.t. $q_1p=1+q_2$.

Comment: The differences between the various Positivstellensatz's, whether they apply solely to strict-positivity or non-negative polynomials, has indeed confused me. However, for the sake of this question, I would be happy to apply a small tolerance $\epsilon > 0$ and ask whether there is a Positivstellensatz-like test which determines whether $|p| \geq \epsilon$ on $S$. This $\epsilon$ can then enter the $\sigma_0$ term if necessary. The question remains, is there a characterization which avoids the squaring operation on $p$.

Comment: It's again unclear whether your $p$ is given, or not. Needless to say, for compact $S$ there is always a quadratic polynomial which is strictly positive on $S$.

Comment: It would help to give an example, or at least the degree and dimension and number of components. I'd also change the title to: "Using semidefinite programming to find polynomials which are non-zero on semialgebraic sets". The *Positivstellensatz* in the current title focuses on a theorem, when you're looking for an algorithm, specifically a semidefinite algorithm. It also focuses on an equation with squares on the right side, which seems unlikely to help avoid squaring on the left.

Comment: Perhaps the question is too open-ended in its current form. Indeed, the RHS involving sums of squares necessitates examining LHSpolynomials which are non-negative on $S$; my intention was to use this kind of Positivstellensatz as motivation to ask if there is a theorem/characterization which is more general and applicable to polynomials that are bounded away from zero on $S$. The suggestion to rephrase in terms of seeking a semidefinite algorithm is a good one, so it might be best to suspend this question and post a new one.

Comment: (And to answer the other question, I'd be targeting medium degree polynomials, say $< 20$, in a small dimension, 2D or 3D, and the number of components of $S$ would typically be only two or three.)